# How to Lazy Load child object with string primary key in Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have an object `User` which references an object `State`. The foreign key is a `string` of `StateID` and is optional. A user is not required to reference a `State`. I have the classes defined as follows

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID {get; set'}
    public string StateID {get; set;}
    //some other properties

    public virtual State State {get; set;}
}


public class State
{
    public string StateID {get; set;}
    //other properties

    public ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

When I try to do a linq query to get some users and their states, the `State` object is always null. I do get the StateID of my User of course so I know that is set properly.

My query looks like this:

```
var users = userRepo.where(x => x.StateID != null);
```

Also tried adding `.ToList()` to get the lazy load to execute which does not work either.

I have tried adding `[key]` annotation to `StateID` in `State` with no luck.

i have also tried giving up on lazy loading and using `include("State")` in my query also with no luck.

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I have also tried to explicitly specify the mapping as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
  .HasOptional(t => t.State)
  .WithMany(b => b.Users)
  .HasForeignKey(t => t.StateID);
```

Comment: Could you show your model configuration? Where did you set that there is relations between this two classes? And did you try to use Include(x=>x.State)?

Comment: Does the SQL logging show any access of the `State` table?

Comment: @Get Arnold No I am not seeing any joins to the State table in the SQL output. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, apparently EF is not aware of the fact that `StateID` is a foreign key. Can you show your mapping configuration?

Comment: Well, with this mapping *and* `Include` *and* `ToList()` I'd certainly expect `State` to be loaded (and lazy loaded without `Include`). Are you absolutely sure that the keys match? (No leading or trailing spaces, case issues)

Comment: @stephen776  You added a `DbSet<State>` to the `DbContext` class?  If so, did you migrate the changes to the Db?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the navigation property is defined correctly in `User` class. like below:

```
   public class User
    {
        public int UserID {get; set;}          
        public string StateID {get; set;}

        //some other properties
        public State State {get; set;}
    }
```

Then you can create a query using `Include` like below:

```
var users = userRepo.Where(i => i.StateID != null).Include("State").ToList();
```

Update:

If you want to use Lazy loading to achieve this, add virtual keyworkd to all navigation properties.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID {get; set;}
    public string StateID {get; set;}
    public virtual State State{get; set;}
}

public class State
{
    public string StateID {get; set;}
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Also make sure you didn't disable Lazy loading in your DbContext class like below:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // disable Lazy loading
```

follow above steps, the Lazy loading should works, below is an example:

In your action method:

```
   ViewBag.Result = userRepo.Users.Where(i => i.StateID != null);
```

In your view

```
    @foreach (User item in @ViewBag.Result)
    {
        <div>@item.State.SomePropertyName</div>
    }
```

Comment: So are you saying it is not possible to lazy load using the virtual keyword on The navigation property?

Comment: Of course it's possible to use lazy loading. From the code you provided, I didn't see anything wrong. It just give you an example to by using Include keyword. I updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: I have specified `virtual` on both ends of the relationship and I am still getting the same results. I have successfully setup these types of relationships before. I am thinking the difference in this situation is the `string` foreign key

Comment: hi @stephen776, from I see, the problem is not about string type foreign key property. I tested both of them using lazy loading and Include, all work for me. Did you execute the query in your view or you just use breakpoint to look at the query result in your action method?

Comment: I thought about that. That's why I give you an example about execute the query in the view. The problem is not about string type foreign key or Lazy loading. The problem is you didn't actually execute the navigation property. Try var users = userRepo.Where(i => i.StateID != null).Include("State").ToList(), it will give you the result you expect, when you use breakpoints to check the result.

Comment: I am calling .ToList() after the call. Mentioned in my original question

Comment: hi @stephen776, another option is change ICollection<> to List<>.

Comment: I am not trying to access user from State though..I am trying to access State from a User. Not sure what changing the User collection on State would do?? Maybe I am not understanding something here...

Comment: I'm not sure if you tested my code. Because you're calling ToList(), the query will show all of information include navigation property. That's wrong. By definition, until you call the navigation property like @item.State.SomePropertyName, using lazy loading it wouldn't give you anything about that information. That's why when you use breakpoints to check the result, you cann't see anything about the State information. You need to execute that.